# Login failed for user 'NT Authority\ANONYMOUS LOGON' when connect to SharePoint web service

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

We encounter "login failed for user 'NT Authority\anonymous Logon' " error when using the SharePoint copy web service CopyIntoItems method for uploading file to SharePoint from custom web page

```
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

We need to use the current user credential for uploading file to SharePoint.

any help will be appreciated.

Web Site details:
only Windows authentication enabled

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find this is down to kerberos not being set up correctly. You want the users credentials to double jump once to the web server and then on to SharePoint. Seems your SharePoint might be getting the web server (presume iis) credentials. We had a similar issue and kerberos was the answer. I am not a systems guy but hopefully this will point you on the right path.

Comment: We deployed to UAT environment and tested with no error occuried, however this error only occuried after we deployed to Production enviroment.